# dell sc1435 ambient temperature -83deg

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

Recently I had a problem with dell sc1435 server - fans run on full speed and it works on 1 CPU only. After connecting IPMI viever it shows ambient temperature of -83 deg so I beleive it is a problem. Any idea how to fix it ??

Krzysztof

Answer (score 1):

The reason of strange ambient temperature was not connected properly cable connector from main board to the sensor. After fixing it temperature was OK.

Using only one CPU was due to damaged main board after trying not listed by dell 8393 CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Your server only has one CPU (a dual core Opteron). If you are not seeing 2 cores, you have a hardware issue or perhaps there is a place in BIOS to set the number of active cores (I seem to recall something like that in the older Dell days).

In my experience, I had an old Dell PE1950 server I stood up 2 years ago until I could improve the internet connection to a remote clinic.  Fan ran at at full speed all the time, and could heard from the lunch room in that building.

There were no devices listed as unknown in Device Manager.

I did some research and there was an obscure IPMI driver or BMC update that needed to be installed.  I updated everything which resolved the problem.  See if you can find the Update Package for Windows.

I am also reading (http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/t/19347435) - where fans run at a higher speed above a certain memory threshold in Dell servers.

Comment: there are two CPU slots, server boots only on one CPU and puts fans in full speed. So I believe its kind of emergency start to notify user that something goes wrong (ambient temp. sensor failure)

Comment: Ah, you are correct, I missed the s for plural in the description on Dell's site.

Have you looked through BIOS to see if all processors/cores are enabled?  

How much RAM is installed?

Do you have all of the current Update Package installed?